# Deploy Flutter and Laravel php mobile app on the host server

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, server, host

currently I doing a mobile app using flutter as frontend and laravel php as backend, usually i need to serve and open xampp to use the local api and database, so what if I dont want locally anymore, buy a server right? any server suggestion for this kind of situation and how to configure that, this is my first time make the app online.

I try the linode host server and the url could access through browser and shows apache web page but I try to replace my local ipv4 address with server ip to call api online but it always say url not working

Answer (score -1):

Using ngrok can be a convenient solution for exposing your local server to the internet temporarily during development or testing phases. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to set up ngrok for your Flutter mobile app with Laravel backend:

1. **Install ngrok**:

   - Go to the ngrok website (https://ngrok.com/) and sign up for an account if you haven't already.
   - Download ngrok for your operating system.
   - Extract the downloaded ngrok file to a directory on your computer.
2. **Run your Laravel server**:

   - Make sure your Laravel backend is running locally using `php artisan serve` or another method you prefer.
3. **Expose your local server with ngrok**:

   - Open a terminal or command prompt.
   - Navigate to the directory where you extracted ngrok.
   - Run the following command to start ngrok and expose your local server:

     ```
     ./ngrok http <port_number>
     ```

     Replace `<port_number>` with the port your Laravel server is running on (usually 8000 or 8000).
4. **Get your ngrok URL**:

   - After running the command, ngrok will provide you with a forwarding URL. It will look something like `http://randomstring.ngrok.io`.
   - This URL is accessible from the internet and forwards requests to your local server.
5. **Update your Flutter app**:

   - Replace the base URL in your Flutter app's API calls with the ngrok URL.
   - For example, if your Laravel backend's base URL was `http://localhost:8000/api`, replace it with the ngrok URL (e.g., `http://randomstring.ngrok.io/api`).
6. **Test your app**:

   - Run your Flutter app.
   - Now your app should be able to communicate with your Laravel backend via the ngrok URL.

Remember, ngrok provides a temporary solution for testing and development purposes. For production, you'll want to deploy your Laravel backend to a proper server. Services like AWS, DigitalOcean, or Linode can be suitable options for hosting your backend. Make sure to secure your server properly before deploying your app in a production environment.

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi: [Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)